# In a normal distribution, are the events mutually exclusive or not, they are conditioned or not?

Tags: normal-distribution

I was solving some normal distribution exercises and the question appeared in the book:

$${\cal N}(10,2)$$

$$P(x < 8\ \vee\ x > 11)$$

So I thought, should I just sum or should subtract the intersection? And if I subtract the intersection, is it from conditioned events $(P (B.A) = P (A) .P (B / A))\ {\rm or\ not}\ (P (B.A) = P (A) .P (B)$?

Was that when I asked myself, in a normal distribution, are the events mutually exclusive or not, they are conditioned or not?

Comment: You have no conditioned probability here. You can determine $$p:=P(8 \le x\le 11)$$ and the result is then $\ 1-p\ $

Comment: @Peter if it was P(x<8 and x>11)? is just equal to P(x<8).P(x>11)  or they are multually exclusive and its zero?

Comment: The other possibility is to add $$P(x<8)$$ and $$P(x>11)$$ because the two events are mutually exclusive. You would get probability $0$ if we had "and" instead of "or" because the two events cannot occur simultaneously (exactly because they are mutually exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

Does this figure help in this problem?

[image]